# Sort children into parent in django template

Tags: django, sorting, filter

I have been trying to figure out this problem while learning Django (Python).

I would like to sort children objects into their parent. Specifically, I want to sort cities into their respective state. Then, I want the city to display in the template in its correct state. What I am looking for would like like this:

State 
--- City 
--- City 
--- City

Edit: I've got it somewhat working. However, the cities are repeating themselves in the template. I only need each one to display once. I've included the template to see if anyone can help me with it.

Thanks again.

models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    state_slug = models.SlugField()
    state_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)
    state_summary = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_slug

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    city_slug = models.SlugField()
    state_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)
    school_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, related_name='+')
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.city_slug
```

views.py

```
class CityInStateView(ListView):
    model = City

    context_object_name = 'city_in_state_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CityInStateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        city = City.objects.all()
        state = State.objects.get(state_slug=self.kwargs['state_slug'])
        context['city_list'] = City.objects.filter(state=state).order_by('city_name')
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', SchoolIndexView.as_view(), name='school_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<state_slug>[\w-]+)/$', CityInStateView.as_view(), name='state_index'),
]
```

template.html

```
{% block main_content %}
<div class="row body">
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="medium-12 columns small-centered">
                <div class="feature_wrapper">
                    {% load cloudinary %}
                    <header class="page_header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="medium-12 columns">Top bar</div>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <div class="search">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="medium-12 columns">Search bar</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if city_in_state_list %}
                    {% for city in city_in_state_list %}
                    <section class="hero">
                        {% cloudinary city.state_image.image format="jpg" crop="fill" %}
                        <p class="photo-caption">
                            {{ city.state_image.image_name }} by {{ city.state_image.image_author }} via {{ city.state_image.image_source }} | {{ city.state_image.image_license }}
                        </p>
                    </section>
                    <section class="summary">
                        <p>{{ city.state.state_summary }}</p>
                    </section>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="medium-12 columns listicle">
                            <div class="demo_wrapper">
                                <div class="long_ad_box">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/728x90">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="state_name">
                            <h2 class="headline">Nursing Schools in {{ city.state.state_name }}</h2>
                        </div>
                        {% if city_list %}
                            {% for school in city_list %}
                            <h2 style="text-align: left";>{{ school.city_name }}</h2>
                            <div class="school_image">
                                {% cloudinary city.school_image.image format="jpg" crop="fill" %}
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>                                  
{% endblock %}
```

This has been kicking my butt for a week. Please explain it to me like I a m five. I appreciate all of your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a DetailView representing the state, rather that a list of cities. This because your URL represents a state's object view.

So, you can

```
class CityInStateView(generic.DetailView):
    model = State
    template_name = 'template.html'
    slug_field = 'state_slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CityInStateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['state'] = self.object
        context['city_list'] = self.object.city_set.all().order_by('city_name')
        return context
```

and then your template (simplified example) would be as simple as:

```
<h1>{{ state.state_name }}</h1>
{% for city in city_list %}
  <p>{{ city.city_name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

For the URL to work with DetailView, and because you did not use `slug` as the field name, you need to tell the DetailView that state_slug is your slug. You may want to add `unique=True` to your model.

Hope you can take it from here

Comment: I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: I am coding without testing so let me know if it does not work and I will fix it

Comment: I have tried it. I am now getting this error: Generic detail view CityInStateView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

Comment: Edited the answer to explain how to fix the slug issue, but that is really a different question which is how to get DetailView to use your state_slug instead of the usual `slug` that you will find in all examples. We check if I can quickly find the answer to that.

Comment: Found it. I believe you can use slug_field on the DetailView, so I edited the answer to show that. The only think you may need is to add `unique=True` to your slug_state on the model to ensure the slug can work as a unique identifier