# Sort subchild into child into parent django

Tags: django, sorting, filter, relationship

This is mainly working (thanks to a lot of help on a previous question. [Sort children into parent in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490410/sort-children-into-parent-in-django-template])

Now I would like to sort sub-children objects into the children objects and then sort the children into their parent. Specifically, I want to sort schools into cities into their respective state. Then, I want the schools to display into the right city in its correct state. What I am looking for would like like this:

State 
--- City 
-----School 
-----School 
-----School 
--- City 
-----School 
-----School 
-----School 
--- City 
-----School 
-----School 
-----School

Right now, I have the cities sorting into the state. However, I cannot figure out to make the schools sort into the city. I am reading up on filters in the documentation. I think the answer lies there. However, I when try to filter the schools into the city, no objects come back.

Is there a way to retrieve the 'school_list' as a child of 'city_list' while still keeping the 'city_list a child of the states ? I would love to learn how.

Edit: Added the School model. Sorting the schools by name inside a city would be ideal.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Edit: dkarchmer's solution worked perfectly. Thanks again. Hopefully, this will be useful to someone else in the future.

models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    state_slug = models.SlugField()
    state_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)
    state_summary = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_slug

class City(models.Model):
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    city_slug = models.SlugField()
    state_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True)
    school_image = models.ForeignKey(Image, null=True, related_name='+')
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.city_slug

def def sorted_schools(self):
    return self.school_set.all().order_by('school_name')

class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=55, default='')
    school_slug = models.SlugField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_slug
```

views.py

```
class CityInStateView(ListView):
    model = City
    template = 'template.html'
    slug_field = 'state_slug'

    context_object_name = 'city_in_state_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CityInStateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['state'] = self.object
        context['city_list'] = self.object.city_set.all().order_by('city_name')
        return context
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', SchoolIndexView.as_view(), name='school_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<state_slug>[\w-]+)/$', CityInStateView.as_view(), name='state_index'),
]
```

template.html

```
{% block main_content %}
<div class="row body">
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="row">
           <h1>{{ state.state_name }}</h1>
            {% for city in city_list %}
               <h2>{{ city.city_name }}</h2>
               {% for school in city.sorted_schools %}
                   <h3>{{ school.school_name }} </h3>
               {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div> 
    </div>
 </div>  
{% endblock %}
```

This has been kicking my butt for a week. Please explain it to me like I a m five. I appreciate all of your help in advance.

Comment: Do you want to sort the schools by name inside a city? Also, please add `School` model.

Comment: School model added. Yes. I would like to sort the schools by name inside a city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is to just add a method to the City model to return Schools:

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...

    def sorted_schools(self):
        return self.school_set.all().order_by('school_name')
```

And then use that directly from the template:

```
<div class="row body">
    <div class="main_content">
        <div class="row">
           <h1>{{ state.state_name }}</h1>
           {% for city in city_list %}
              <h2>{{ city.city_name }}</h2>
              {% for school in city.sorted_schools %}
                  <h3>{{ school.school_name }} </h3>
              {% endfor
           {% endfor %}
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to add that method to the Model, the second alternative is to use a templatetag to basically do the same.